# Problem accessing SQL Compact database file on Vista 32 bit

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm building a C# Winforms / .NET 3.5 / Visual Studio 2008 application that uses SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1. After building a setup / msi project and deploying the app on a clean XP machine it works fine. However when I install it on a Vista 32 bit machine, I get the error below:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': The specified module could not be found
```

The app installs fine and the error happens when I run the .exe. In both cases the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll file is in the application directory along with the exe. I've spent hours googling this trying to track down the problem. What I have found so far is that it's a known issue on Vista 64 bit, but I can't find anyone that has the issue on 32 bit Vista. After getting the problem on Vista I changed the target platform to x86 as people have suggested with the 64 bit problem, but tis didn't fix the issue. SQL Compact 3.5 is 32 bit so I don't see why this is happening on 32 bit Vista.

Comment: Did you get any error code with that?  Something like 0x8007007E

Comment: And you include all the SQL Compact DLL files in your application directory?

Comment: Iain - sorry for the delay getting back to you. The error code I get is 0x8007007E.    
Erik - I only include System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll. I read somewhere that this is the only dll needed.

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem which @ErikEJ was probably alluding to. I packaged the rest of the SQL CE dll files with the msi and installed them to the application folder, so this seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok haven't had any official answer to this so gonna answer it myself, although @ErikEJ alluded to it in a comment. The problem was that I needed to package all the SQL CE dll files (listed below) and not just System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll. Once I did this the problem was sorted.

- sqlceca35.dll
- sqlcecompact35.dll
- sqlceer35en.dll
- sqlceoledb35.dll
- sqlceqp35.dll
- sqlcese35.dll